# When not the author, how do I handle a incorrectly marked duplicate question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I have a question I noticed from someone else.

[Reactive Command thread error when accessing variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57071585/reactive-command-thread-error-when-accessing-variable)

The question was marked as a duplicate, with people lodging answers with standard WPF based dispatcher approaches.

In the question though it's talking about ReactiveUI which uses a different threading methodology called observables from the Reactive Extensions.

If you mix observables with the dispatcher your code can get into deadlock situations.

I flagged the content as per a few articles from here recommended explaining while it seemed similar it's actually not a duplicate due to the above reasons.

I got that flag declined.

I was wondering how to actually solve this?

I am not the original author of the question, so the normal resolution that is available to the author is not available to me and other questions I have found don't answer in that context.

Comment: You should edit the question to highlight why it's not a duplicate. Flags are another thing altogether. What kinda flag did you use there?

Comment: Especially, note the *When trying clarify or explain, do not do this in comments, but edit the question.* part.

Comment: BDL: Don't think it's a duplicate of that question due to it being in relation to the original author.

Comment: @Glenn it's the same actions:edit to clarify why it's not a duplicate. Whether or not it's your question doesnt change what you should do

Comment: @GlennWatson: I don't think there is any other path than editing the question to make clear why it's not a duplicate. Also note, that op of the question rewrote it completely after it has been closed. The question asked now is only partially related to [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57071585/1). The better option (imho) would be to rollback the edit and leave the question closed.

Comment: @GlennWatson: I talk about the SO question you ask about. Not the meta question. op of the SO question edit their question to something different after it got closed. [Original](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57071585/1).

Comment: Thanks BDL. Makes sense now